# JSON Complex Array Parsing in JavaScript from API

Tags: php, json, api, parsing

Background of the question> ok so i am trying different techniques to accomplish something in creating a web dashboard .Starting off with a html page having button that upon clicking would call an api request which is not open display the json response in a table. Rather than in a default string manner. What im doing is I thought of using the approach of first saving the api request to a .json file and then make it read which is shown above by using java script. On the other hand i have created a .php file which displays the json response . i used postman code curl php to test the api which displayed the response. Now how do I call it over here in the JavaScript the php file.

Below is the JSON data that I'm getting via my API. I have saved this as `thinker.json` file. I want to show data part in a table without removing information mentioned above `data` array:

e.g 
`Name` `Mac` `Status`

### XYZ  ABC 1

```
{
    "action":"list_host",
    "type":"all",
    "ack":"ok",
    "count":"3",
    "page":"1",
    "data":[
        {
            "name":"Host_34F60E",
            "mac":"C8EEA634F60E",
            "status":"0",
            "mark":""
        },
        {
            "name":"K-Electric",
            "mac":"5004BA2C9693",
            "status":"1",
            "mark":""
        },
        {
            "name":"Host_2C94E0",
            "mac":"00F4162C9693",
            "status":"0",
            "mark":""
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I do this?
If I remove the information above the `data` array. So the JSON would be like this:

```
{
    "data":[
        {
            "name":"Host_34F60E",
            "mac":"C8EEA634F60E",
            "status":"0",
            "mark":""
        },
        {
            "name":"K-Electric",
            "mac":"5004BA2C9693",
            "status":"1",
            "mark":""
        },
        {
            "name":"Host_2C94E0",
            "mac":"00F4162C9693",
            "status":"0",
            "mark":""
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm successful by using this code but removed the information above `data`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("thinker.json", function (data) {
        var thinker_data = '';
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            thinker_data += '<tr>';
            thinker_data += '<td>' + value.name + '</td>';
            thinker_data += '<td>' + value.mac + '</td>';
            thinker_data += '<td>' + value.status + '</td>';
            thinker_data += '</tr>';
        });
        $('#thinker_table').append(thinker_data);
    });
});
```

I'm using CURL PHP function to get the data.

---

I have applied same functionality to get the macros data like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("routines.json", function(macros)
```

But what if i also want to access the mac value aswell from the below json response by using the same above java script code?

```
{
    "amount": 4,
    "macros": [
        {
            "name": "Morning",
            "id": 1,
            "type": "onekey"
        },
        {
            "name": "Evening",
            "id": 2,
            "type": "onekey"
        },
        {
            "name": "Meeting Mode",
            "id": 3,
            "type": "onekey"
        },
        {
            "name": "Presentation Mode",
            "id": 4,
            "type": "onekey"
        }
    ],
    "ack": "ok",
    "action": "list_macro",
    "type": "all",
    "mac": "xxxxxxxx"
}
```

---

Ok so after this how can I call that php file which uses the curl option to show the api response over here in the main index.php file where I have written this JavaScript

Comment: Did you try `$.each(data.data, function(key, value){` ?

Comment: The code is javascript, but you asked for parsing in php. Confused?

Comment: any possible solution.

Comment: It worked guillaume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just access "data" property like this `data.data`

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("thinker.json", function(data){
     var thinker_data = '';
     $.each(data.data, function(key, value){
        thinker_data += '<tr>';
        thinker_data += '<td>'+value.name+'</td>';
        thinker_data += '<td>'+value.mac+'</td>';
        thinker_data += '<td>'+value.status+'</td>';
        thinker_data += '</tr>';      
     });
     $('#thinker_table').append(thinker_data);
    }); 
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well a few things..

1. You should get into the habit of using promises vs. inline callbacks. Inline callbacks create "Callback hell"
2. You use be using something like handlebars to do the manipulation to the DOM, not injecting raw HTML into it. (It's slower and not maintainable).
3. JQuery offers a way to use promises vs. callbacks. well JavaScript does this natively now through async but anyway, promises let you be more methodical in the way you interrupt your data response.

A few links for future references:

1. https://medium.com/@js_tut/the-great-escape-from-callback-hell-3006fa2c82e
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures
3. https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/
4. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

And some code..

```
(function(){
    // closurers are your friend
    var updateTable = (function () {
        // get dataset and manipulate it
        return function datasetManipulator(...dataSet){
            if (dataSet.length == 0) {
                throw new ReferenceError('Data from external request was empty.');
            }
            var htmlSet = '';
            // ES6+ lets use do this more natively
            dataSet.forEach(dataItem => {
               htmlSet += '<tr>';
               htmlSet += '<td>' + (dataItem.name) + '</td>';
               htmlSet += '<td>' + (dataItem.mac) + '</td>';
               htmlSet += '<td>' + (dataItem.status) + '</td>';
               htmlSet += '</tr>';  
            });
            return htmlSet;
        }
    })();
    // function to handle data on the return
    var queryJsonApi = (function () {
        // after query is done, check for data.data, 
        // send an empty object back if nothing
        return function jsonSuccess(data) {
            return (typeof data.data !== 'undefined' ? data.data : {})
        }
    })();
    // function to handle distroying the performance of the page with DOM manipulations
    var completeJsonQuery = (function() {
        var htmlTable = '';
        // update the page DOM with new dataset
        return function domUpdate(dataSet) {
            if (htmlTable == '') {
                htmlTable = $("#thinker_table");
            }
            htmlTable.append(updateTable(dataSet));
            return htmlTable;
        }
    })();
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var jqxhr = null;
        jqxhr = $.getJSON("thinker.json", queryJsonApi)
                    .done(completeJsonQuery)
                    .fail(function jsonFailed() {
                        console.log("something failed.");
                    })
                    .always(function jsonAlways() {
                        console.log("always fire success or failure.");
                    });

        // Set another completion function for the request above
        jqxhr.complete(function jsonComplete() {
           console.log("The reasoning is finished. Fire this event.");
        });
    });
})();
```